# Problem with \includepdf in LyX

Tags: lyx, pdfpages

I am trying to make a different pdf in my LyX document the first pages. When I go to include it, including `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}},pages=-` in the LaTeX options, I get a blank page for my first page.

I've checked to make sure that I haven't selected a `Title` format as to force a page break, so I am stuck.